# Is it possible to get the calling instance inside a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The general reason I want to do this is:

```
class MovieApiController : ApiController
{
    public string CurrentUser {get;set;}

    // ...

    public string Index()
    {
        return Resources.GetText("Color");
    }
}


class Resources
{
    static string GetText(string id)
    {
        var caller = ??? as MovieApiController;
        if (caller && caller.CurrentUser == "Bob")
        {
            return "Red";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Blue";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need this to be 100% dependable. It seems like the callstack should have this information, but `StackFrame` doesn't seem to expose any information about the specific object on which each frame executes.

Comment: You could add an `object caller` parameter to `GetText`.

Comment: That would work of course, but in practice there are lots and lots of places where `GetText` is called, and I want to swap the text whenever it comes from a specific class.

Comment: You're going to simply get yourself into a situation where you're maintaining a huge switch or if-else-if construct. That's not a good use of OO here. You should simply implement a common interface or subclass here. Each ApiController can have its own implementation of GetText. Or you could use a generic on each Resources class. Or you could pass the Class to the GetText method, if you really require it, but it doesn't look like you really do here. There's a better way of implementing this that does not involve what you're trying to do at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a bad idea for a method to try to "sniff" its surroundings, and produce different results based on who is making the call.

A better approach is to make your `Resources` class aware of whatever it needs to know in order to make its decision, and configure it in a place where all relevant information is known, for example

```
class MovieApiController : ApiController {
    private string currentUser;
    private Resources resources;
    public string CurrentUser {
        get {
            return currentUser;
        }
        set {
            currentUser = value;
            resources = new Resources(currentUser);
        }
    }
    // ...

    public string Index() {
        return resources.GetText("Color");
    }
}

class Resources {
    private string currentUser;
    public Resources(string currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }
    public string GetText(string id) {
        if (currentUser == "Bob") {
            return "Red";
        } else {
            return "Blue";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed; however, I am more interested in how to perform the operation specified in the question (or know why it is impossible) than in workarounds to simply not perform the operation. I should have used different example code, as it is apparently obfuscating what I'm really trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentUser` should be available at `HttpContext.Current.User` and you can leave your controller out of the resource class.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like the callstack should have this information,

Why?  The call stack indicated what *methods* are called to get where you are at - it does not have any information about *instances*.

Rethink your parameters be deciding what information does the method need to do its job.  Reaching outside of the class (e.g. by using the callstack or taking advantage of static methods like `HttpContext.Current`) limit the re-usability of your code.

From what you've shown, all you need is the current user name (you don't even show where you use the `id` value.  If you want to return different things based on what's passed in then maybe you need separate methods?

As a side note, the optimizer has a great deal of latitude in reorganizing code to make it more efficient, so there are no guarantees that the call stack even contains what you think it should from the source code.

Comment: I believe the call stack is actually what methods will be called after your current method completes (which is usually also the place you came from). So if the current method is going to return to a particular location in a method and restore the stack to the expected state, it should know what the 'this' pointer is for that method.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't, short of creating a custom controller factory that stores the current controller as a property of the current `HttpContext`, and even that could prove unpredictable.

But it's really not good for a class to behave differently by attempting to inspect its caller. When a method depends on another class it needs to get the correct behavior by depending on the right class, calling the right method, and passing the right parameters.

So in this case you could

- have a parameter that you pass to `GetResources` that tells it what it needs to know in order to return the correct string.
- Create a more specific version of the `Resources` class that does what you need
- declare

  ```
  public interface IResources
  {
      string GetText(string id);
  }
  ```

And have multiple classes that implement `IResources`, use dependency injection to provide the correct implementation to this controller. Ideally that's the best scenario. `MovieApiController` doesn't know anything about the implementation of `IResources`. It just knows that there's an instance of `IResources` that will do what it needs. And the `Resource` class doesn't know anything about what is calling it. It behaves the same no matter what calls it.

That would look like this:

```
public class MovieApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IResources _resources;

    public MovieApiController(IResources resources)
    {
        _resources = resources;
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        return _resources.GetText("Color");
    }
}
```

Notice how the controller doesn't know anything about the `Resources` class. It just knows that it has something that implements `IResources` and it uses it.

If you're using ASP.NET Core then dependency injection is [built in](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html).  (There's some good reading in there on the general concept.) If you're using anything older then you can still add it in.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection - This has a picture that is worth 1000 words for describing the concept.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-ioc-using-unity-in-mvc-5/

Some of these recommend understanding "inversion of control" first. You might find it easier to just implement something according to the example without trying to understand it first. The understanding comes when you see what it does.